# Why I can't get a desired result

Tags: lua

Hey Can anybody help me with my lua code?

```
table1 = {
    "Apple",
    "Orange",
}

table2= {
    "je",
}

table.Merge(table1,table2)

print( table.concat(table1," ") )
```

It should give me a result of a table "je","Orange" but I got some error messeges

**Test.lua:10: attempt to call a nil value (field 'Merge')
stack traceback:
d:\GMOD_dream\server_STUFF\server script.vscode\Test.lua:10: in main chunk
[C]: in ?
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command lua54 'd:\GMOD_dream\server_STUFF\server script.vscode\Test.lua'" terminated with exit code: 1.**

Appreciate it if you can help me!

Comment: Spelling matters.  The function is `table.merge`, not `table.Merge`.

Comment: Someone said it was spelling but it displays the same error even if I use merge instead of “Merge”

Comment: Please update the question with your new error.

Comment: There is neither `table.Merge` nor `table.merge` in the Lua standard library.

Answer (score 2):

> Test.lua:10: attempt to call a nil value (field 'Merge')

is caused by `table.Merge(table1,table2)`.  `table.Merge` is nil. Calling nil values does not make any sense and is hence prompted with the observed error.

Unless you define it, there is no `table.Merge`.

`table` is Lua's [Table Manipulation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.6) library.

You can use [table.move](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.move)

```
print(table.concat(table.move(table2, 1, #table2, #table1+1, table1), ", "))
```

Or a simple loop that appends each element of table2 to table1, assuming that's what you understand by "merge".